# Ghana visa - Yellow Fever requirements

Tags: visas, ghana

Looking at the Tourist Visa requirements for Ghana (for a UK Citizen) it states that the Yellow Fever vaccination must be within the last 10 years.  My Yellow Fever vaccination was in 2012 and my certificate gives an expiry date of 2022.  I know that Yellow Fever vaccinations now last for the life of the patient.  Will I have issues if I use my "expired" certificate when I apply for the visa?  I have tried to email the Ghana High Commission, but have had no reply.

Comment: Where do you see this requirement?

Comment: Is it simpler and cheaper to do a new vaccination? Now vaccinations may last for life, but are you sure it was so in the past? (IIRC there were more freedom on when to do the second vaccination, which may shorten the effect. Also doses may have changed). And the effectiveness doesn't matter (but for you): you should follow the rules.

Comment: I finally got through to the Ghana High Commission and was told that the Yellow Fever Certificate with an expiry date needed to be replaced with one that said "valid for life".  As the place where I had my original jab has now closed, and everywhere else says they will only replace a certificate if they did the original jab, I have decided that it is easier to get another vaccination, as Giacomo Catenazzi suggested.